# Wordpress Admin Multiple Posts

Tags: wordpress

I have been searching for a while now and wondered if any of you have a solution:

I would like to create another button in the admin dashboard and it be the same as the original "post" except it's linked to its own category.  Or if I can simply add buttons that go directly to a post category and remove the 'main' post button?

Comment: insert the code you tried so that we can help you fixing it...

Comment: I don't really have a code that was close.  I just copied single.php and tried to make another button for the new name.  

What may be easier is to simply call pages from JSON API, but I can't seen to figure out how to do it.  I read a few things but nothing seems to be working.   I can get posts, not pages.

Comment: sorry, man, won't be able to help without code...

Comment: kinda like custom post types?

Comment: Basically I'm building a site and they are completely ignorant in anything tech.  She asked me instead of having to go to "posts", then select the correct category.. could there just be two buttons on the side.. one goes directly to Category A and the other goes directly to Category B with them automatically selected.